# How to transfer videos from Mac to iPhone so I can post a video to Instagram?

Tags: iphone, mac, video, instagram

I created a 15 second video on my Mac and want to post it to Instagram.

I've tried converting it to Quicktime with iTunes and adding it to the iPhone that way, but I can't see the video in the Photos on the iPhone.

I've also tried reducing the file size and emailing it to myself and opening the email on the iPhone and downloading the attachment, but it doesn't load it to Photos so I can't access the video anywhere on the phone. I've even tried opening the mail attachment video in a video editor on my iphone, "videoshop," which supposedly saves the video to my Camera roll, but again, I can't see the video in Photos, so I can't upload the video.

Mac is system 10.7.5
iPhone 5 with iOS 8.3

Answer (score 10):

You can use AirDrop to send files from Mac to iPhone. You can read more about it here https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203106

Comment: True, but unfortunately, older Macs (even those capable of running Yosemite) don't support this feature, as it requires Bluetooth LE. Plus, the user is only running Lion, which means that Mac to Mac is possible, but Mac to iOS device requires Yosemite.

Answer (score 5):

When you drag the video into iTunes and sync with your iPhone, the video goes into the Videos app, under Home Movies, not Photos.  While you can watch it there, your iPhone treats it like a TV show or movie synced, so you cannot post it to Instagram from there.

What you want to do is open both iTunes and Messages on your Mac. Create an iMessage conversation **with yourself** and then go into iTunes and drag the video into the text field of the iMessage conversation with yourself. Now just send it to yourself and it will appear on Messages on your iPhone. In Messages on your iPhone, tap and hold the video until a popover appears. Select "Save" and the video goes straight to Photos. I've done this many times to get videos from Final Cut Pro X to my iPhone so that I can post them on Vine.

Comment: thx, a nice trick

Answer (score 1):

This may be too late, but I had the same problem this evening and just found a solution.

Create a folder on your desktop or in pictures- put your video files in there.

Attach your phone via usb lead to your computer and open itunes.

Once your device is showing in itunes, click the "Pictures" option.

You'll have an option which says "Copy photos from"

From there, choose the folder you added your video clips to.
Make sure the "Include videos" box is ticked

Sync your phone.

The clips will now be saved in "videos"

To instagram them, open instagram, go to add a photo as you usually would (by clicking the little camera icon in the middle)

At the top center of the screen, click the downward pointing arrow, which usually says something like "Camera Roll" next to it. You'll then be able to select "Videos"

Your videos should be in there for you to select to upload.

It took a bit of figuring out, but I got there in the end.

There might be a really simple, easy way around this, but hopefully this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

I have one solution that works with Google Drive.

1. Upload your video to Google Drive from your desktop.
2. From your iPhone open the Google Drive app and locate your video.
3. Select the three dots next to the video you want to upload to instagram.
4. Select the "Send a copy" menu item
5. Select Instagram from the apps you would like to send the video to. Done.
6. If Instagram isn't available as an option, select the "more" option and turn on Instagram so it will show in your list of apps to share with.

I haven't tried One Drive yet but I can to see if there is a procedure that works.

Cheers,

Sam

Answer (score 0):

You can send the video to yourself by email, and open it on the iphone with stock ios Photos app, or you can upload it to a cloud service like Dropbox from PC and download it via iphone's Dropbox app. These are the options if you don't have a mac/iphone capable of AirDrop.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a few of these and while some of them work, video quality is degraded. My take is to just let [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) sync the data to/from your phone and desktop computer. :)

Answer (score -1):

This is good to know but you still would not be able to upload to Instagram from the photos app in iPhone. I don't believe the photos app supports Instagram at all. There are some third party apps that can create a work around but it's pretty labor intensive.

Answer (score -1):

If you cannot successfully transfer videos from Mac to iPhone with iTunes, then you may consider using other tools like AirDrop, AirMore, they are easy to use. I can successfully do this trick with these tools.